# Joining two tables and need to return results which have same ID but different criteria

Tags: sql

I'm pretty stuck at the moment due to by lack of SQL knowledge!

I have two tables with the following criteria:

```
Table1

UPC  
Country

Table2

UPC  
Country
```

I need to see all of the rows in Table 1 with the corresponding UPC from Table two and where a country is missing from table 2.

So for example:

```
UPC1    |Country1   |UPC2   |Country2  
12345   |UK     |12345  |UK  
12345   |IE     |12345  |IE
12345   |DE     |NULL   |NULL
12345   |FR     |12345  |FR
```

I've tried the following code:

```
select *
from CPRSLRScheduled cprs join R2LRDig r2
    on cprs.UPC = r2.upc
where cprs.country_iso_code not in (r2.country_id)
```

I know this is a real beginners' question but I really need a helping hand!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an outer join. The following statement gives you all records of table 1 and the matches of table 2. If no match is found, you get NULL values:

```
select *
from CPRSLRScheduled cprs 
left outer join R2LRDig r2 on cprs.UPC = r2.upc and cprs.country_iso_code = r2.country_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.upc,t1.country,t2.upc,t2.country 
from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2 
on t1.upc=t2.upc where t2.country IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a `left outer join`:

```
select *
from CPRSLRScheduled cprs left outer join
     R2LRDig r2
     on cprs.UPC = r2.upc and
        cprs.country_iso_code = r2.country_id
where r2.upc is NULL;
```

This takes all the rows from the scheduled table and tries to find a match in the other table based on `upc` and the country code.  If there is no match, the row is still kept, but the values for the second table are given `NULL` values.  So, the final `where` clause is selecting the values that are in the first table but not the second.

Comment: If not otherwise specified, isn't `JOIN` a synonym for `INNER JOIN` rather than `LEFT OUTER JOIN`?